# There are four standard radio buttons on a form. How do you make the first pair work independently of the second pair

Tags: delphi, radio-button

There are four standard radio buttons on a form. How do you make the first pair work independently of the second pair

is linking them to event is the best way to do ??

Comment: Can you post your code? What have you tried?

Comment: @JeremyW, not **every** question needs to have code attached. This question is perfectly fine as is.

Comment: Did you look at the [Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TRadioButton) for radio buttons?

Comment: @Johan Noted. Should help with reviewing in the future. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Radio buttons are grouped when they have a common `Parent`. So put the two pairs in separate `Parent` containers.  You can use `TRadioGroup`, `TGroupBox`, `TPanel`, etc for that.

Comment: Indeed. Even linking them to actions with different `GroupIndex` properties set results in one single group when placed on the same parent.

Comment: @NGLN: The `GroupIndex` property of an action does not control how radio buttons are grouped together within their `Parent`. The `GroupIndex` affects how the action's `Checked` property behaves in relation to the `Checked` property of other actions.

Comment: I know! But that certainly works as [radio items](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ActnList_TAction_GroupIndex.html): _GroupIndex is used to define groups of actions that act like radio buttons._ I just meant to say that apparently the parent has precedence over GroupIndex setting.

Comment: hi, I was actually going through some question paper where i came across this question . below are the options given. I got confused so have posted them here                                                                            a) Place each pair on their own panel.                                                   b) Give each pair the same name.
C) Give each pair a different tag number.
d) Surround each pair with a bevel.
e) Edit the OnClick event to check only the radio buttons required.
f) Correct option not shown

Comment: @Ashokkumar A and D are the same thing. B is not an option. C does not control grouping at all, Tag is just a user-defined value. E will not work if the buttons all have the same Parent. A/D is the best option.